# What is the probability that the second number that is divisible by 5 is drawn before the third number that is not divisible by 5?

Tags: probability

> An urn contains 25 tickets numbered from 1 to 25.Tickets are drawn
>   from the urn in succession, with replacement.
>
> What is the probability that the second number that is divisible by 5
>   is drawn before the third number that is not divisible by 5?

I understand that I should use the negative binomial however I don’t know how and what event should I assess as success and what event should I assess as failure and when I apply the formula I always get different answer which, the correct one, must be $0.181$. can you please help me?
Thanks you for all your detailed and correct answers? Can I find the same answer using the negative binomial?

Comment: Note that since the drawing is with replacement, the tickets numbered 5, 10, 15, 20, 25 are indistinguishable from one another, and the other twenty tickets are indistinguishable from one another. So it suffices to pretend that there are only the tickets 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 in the urn. (Or, that there are only two tickets, "divisible-by-5" and "not-divisible-by-5", drawn with probabilities $\frac15$ and $\frac45$, respectively.)

Comment: This is perhaps best done with a tree, since there will be very few branches to evaluate.

Comment: How many times do you draw out the tickets?

Comment: Think about the maximum number of tickets that can drawn before one of the events occurs.  This is a small problem.

Comment: can you please elaborate more on that?

Comment: 3rd number not divisible by 5 is 3 ? And second number divisible by 5 is 10?

Comment: Thanks you a lot for your attempts. but I really did not get it. first, I did not know why we considered the prob of balls not divisible by 5 as being 4/5 and the one divisible by 5 is 1/5 although there are 25 balls. Next, according to your answer I tried to make 4 chains.Let’s 1 be the number designating the ball not divisible by 5 and 5 be the number designating the ball divisible by 5, then I can simply draw the following chains: 55,551,5511,55111 and in that case why would I only be computing the probability of one chain.In addition, considering independence I did not get the correct answ

Comment: $5/25=1/5;\ 20/25=4/5$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be easier to think about the probability that three numbers not divisible by $5$ come first.  Call it a success if the number isn't divisible by $5$ and failure if it is. The probability of success is $.8$ on any draw.  If we have three success before two failures, then we got at most one failure so the game lasts $4$ turns at most.

If we got no failures, then the first three draws were successes; the probability of this is $.8^3.$  If we had one failure, it must have happened on one of the first $3$ draws; the probability of this is $3\cdot.2\cdot.8^3.$  The probability that we had three successes before two failures is the sum of these, but the problem asks for the complement, so the answer is $$1-.8^3-3\cdot.2\cdot.8^3=.1808$$

Comment: So as I can infer, the probability of having 3 successes before 2 failures is the complement of that having two failures before 3 successes?

Comment: @Rayen Yes, that's what I mean.

Comment: And what if we had 4 successes or more before we get the first failure

Comment: The game is over as soon as we get $3$ successes.

Comment: Sorry if I am asking you a lot of questions, but I found the notion of complement really intriguing . how in general do I determine the complement of an event is there like a rule or something because sometimes I can find it obvious and sometimes it’s intriguing. I know it’s a bit off-topic but I would really appreciate your answer

Comment: It just mean that the event doesn't happen -- it's the same as set complement.  Do you know De Morgan's laws?

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

If $E$ denotes the event that the second number that is divisible by $5$ is drawn before the third number that is not divisible by $5$ then:$$P(E)=P(DD)+P(DND)+P(DNND)+P(NDD)+P(NDND)+P(NNDD)$$where e.g. $DND$ denotes the event that first a number is drawn divisible by $5$, then a number not divisible by $5$ and then a number divisible by $5$.

Comment: How can I get the same answer using the negative binomial?